# JavaScript function - Global Namespace

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-namespaces

In Javascript, there exists a function which inherits the Backbone Model

```
window.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ .. .. });
window.MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ .. .. });
```

In another, JS file we access this function as

```
var MyModelInstance = new window.MyModel();
```

Requirement is, all functions needs to be prefixed with specific global namespace (for example, company name 'Google') instead of generic keyword 'window'. How can we achieve it?

I tried the following, but with no success.

```
var googleNameSpace= defineNamespace("Google");

googleNameSpace.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ .. .. });
googleNameSpace.MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ .. .. });



var MyModelInstance = new Google.MyModel();
```

Answer (score 1):

in all files add this line at first

```
window.googleNameSpace = googleNameSpace || {};
```

**update:** ok you need google as namespace then have it like this

```
function defineNamespace(str) {
    window[str] = window[str] || {};
    return window[str];
}



googleNamespace = defineNamespace('Google');
```

will work now

Comment: This looks good. But, what if the Name Space is 'Google.Module1'?

Comment: you may need to write lil bit more code..like split them first and keep checking word by word for the package...

Comment: Its not working.. giving out the error namely 'Uncaught TypeError: Object is not a function:20".   At line 20, I am calling                          var MyModelInstance = new Google.MyModel();

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to prefix things with `window` as this is assumed. you could define

```
window.myNamespace = Backbone.Model.extend({ .. .. });
```

and then refer to it only with:

```
myNameSpace.....
```

e.g.

```
window.myModule.helpers = {
    ....
};
```

can be referenced by:

```
myModule.helper.{{property/method}}
```

Comment: Its throwing error namely 'Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function:20'